# maven structure issue based on unpacking signed jars

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-shade-plugin

I am working on standalone application using maven.
I have tried following scenarios,
 1. Using maven shade plugin
       it unpacking all the dependencies so my signed jars(bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar) are unpacked. so lost the jar's sign because of this am getting security exception "jce cannot authenticate the provider bc".
  2. Using maven assembly plugin (based on assembly.xml) and maven jar plugin (to set class path for all jars)
       Here i have implemented to move all the dependencies to lib folder and created my project jar without dependencies finally i have grouped as zip file. this logic fixed security exception issue my application working fine. But here i need to move only bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar into lib folder other jars need to be in my application jar itself.

But i need to do the following structure

```
zip
 |
  -- MyProject.jar
     |
      -- unpacked dependancies (except signed dependancies)
 | 
  --  lib folder
       |
        -- signed jar (bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar)
```

Comment: What is exactly your question?

Comment: I want to move only one jar to lib folder without unpacking jar and access that jar by adding manifest classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have jars within jars. Unless you use a hack like jar-jar. You should just keep all your dependencies in the lib folder. It is much simpler.